# Can someone explain the long string at the end of the ICON property from each link in a Chrome bookmark export file?

Tags: html, google-chrome, bookmarks

What is the purpose of the long string at the end of the ICON property? From the sample, "iVB...II="

```
<A HREF="http://www.gmail.com/" ADD_DATE="0" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Gmail</A>
```

Comment: It's the base64 encoded representation of the icon. That string makes up the image. Encoding it in the link saves one extra http request.

Comment: Thank you! I was also just reading about embedding files server-side and this helps to visualize the overall file transfer process.